# JavaScript API doesn't give error but also doesn't return data?

Tags: javascript, rest, express

file 1:

```
    var setupController = require('./controllers/setupController');
    app.route('/api/pace')
      .get(gameController.getPace);
```

file 2:

```
    var paceData = require("../models/pace");
    var thePace = paceData.getPaceData();

    exports.getPace = function(req, res) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.send(thePace);
    }
```

file 3:

```
    var pace = {
      id: 0,
      paceName: \["steady", "strenuous", "grueling", "resting"\],
      milesPerDay: \[10, 30, 50, 0\],
      healthChange: \[-1, -3, -8, 0\]
    }

    exports.getPaceData = function(){
      return pace;
    }
```

I'm trying to call the data so I can use it in a different file using API. It doesn't seem to get the correct data and idk why. I'm using this site to test the api: https://reqbin.com/ whenever I put it in it says it works but doesn't show data.

Comment: The first issue you have is this code is Javascript. And not Java. Which might be part of the problem.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java to me or I'm totally lost with the latest Java syntax.

Comment: Have you verified `thePace` is what you think it is in "file 2"? Have you verified the network request what you expect? And you handler is handling it? There's not much else we can offer w/ the information provided.

Comment: I'd expect that code to throw a syntax error at all the ```\``` characters floating around file 3 and refuse to compile in the first place.